# How to auto open modal popup on Enter page

Tags: php, javascript, modalpopupextender

Can someone me to open the modal popup when a vistor requests the page for the very first time, a cokie hides it thereafter. I need to do a survey. They answer one question and are redirected so a close button or submit button is not needed. Im using php.

Thanks for the help.
Bruce

Answer (score -1):

Are you allowed to use jQuery? I would user jQuery + jQuery-UI (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

What you have to do is just define a Div element with the markup of the popup, and then invoke the popup method used by jQuery UI in the document ready event.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {$( "#dialog" ).dialog();});
```

and

```
<div id="dialog"> Here goes your survey form</div>
```

Also it is a good idea to load jQuery and jQuery-UI from a CDN, like google's, use these addresses:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js
```

Hope this helps